# "Recently Bookmarked" bookmarks in Firefox lost

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I accidentally deleted my Recently Bookmarked Bookmarks feed in Firefox. How can I bring it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into organize bookmarks. Click on third button on the top (Import and Backup) and go into restore. Pick the previous day and hit ok. This will restore all of your previous bookmarks from yesterday.

Comment: The 3rd button is called Import and Backup

Answer (score 3):

1. Firefox Menu`>`Bookmarks`>`Show All Bookmarks
2. Right click`>`New Bookmark
3. Use:

   - Name = Recently Bookmarked
   - Location = `place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&excludeItemIfParentHasAnnotation=livemark%2FfeedURI&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1`
4. Click `Add`

Bonus: notice `maxResults=10`, you can increase it to see more than 10.

Comment: This still works as of Firefox 82.0.2 (2020/12).

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate it using the special places URLs which query bookmarks using SQLite. It can be overkill for this part, however.

You can, for example, increase the amount of "Recent bookmarks" displayed.

See also forum post *[Places query syntax](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3260477)*.