# How can "lost" Firefox bookmarks be restored?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I just did a routine upgrade of my Firefox from 3.6.4 to 3.6.6 and lost most of my bookmarks.  The bookmarks I have now are the ones I had about six months ago.  Nothing that happened during the update process indicated any kind of problem to me (warnings, crashes, "unable to update foo at this time" messages).  I did update a handful of add-ons for 3.6.6; mostly big ones like AdBlock Plus, Greasemonkey and the like.

I've found three resources about this but none were useful:

- [SU question about FF bookmark loss](https://superuser.com/questions/26339/recently-bookmarked-bookmarks-in-firefox-lost)

  - No luck, the last backup was made today after the problem started, and the previous one was made six months ago
- [Mozilla forum thread about bookmark issues](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=258366)

  - Last activity in 2006, and it only describes pre-FF3 bookmarks
- [Mozilla forum thread about profiles](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=261801)

  - Simply didn't work

The one thing I did glean from those resources is that FF seems to like to keep lots of copies of bookmarks around.  Is there somewhere else I can go to manually restore the old ones, or at least find the URLs so I can load them and re-bookmark them manually?  A more automatic solution would be preferred, but I'm not holding out too much hope for that.

Comment: You should look into xmarks... might save you some trouble in the future. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410/

Comment: Thanks, that does look useful.  Although I might just use this as an opportunity to test-drive Chrome or Opera as my primary browser.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 1.5 and above, 5 daily bookmark backup files are saved in the "bookmarkbackups" folder (in `.json` format), located in the Firefox profile folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user_name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\bookmarkbackups
```

Mozilla states that **you must recover one of these 5 backups before they are overwritten by newer versions.** In your case, it is strange that

> the last backup was made today after
>   the problem started, and the previous
>   one was made six months ago.

Did you check that whether Firefox created a new profile after the update? If there is only one profile, I don't think you can find your lost bookmarks anymore.

Comment: I thought that was strange too, I'm glad it's not just me.  I do have five backup files, but four of them are at least six months old, and the most recent one is useless.  FF did not create a new profile; I have separate profiles for FF 3.5 (now 3.6) and FF 2, but I haven't used FF 2 (either the browser or the profile) in almost a year.

Comment: It is now useless to say that the reason for FF couldn't create proper bookmark backups could be that your `places.sqlite` file somehow got corrupted. Mozilla has a solution for this whereas it's useless in your case: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locked_or_damaged_places.sqlite